# Tilt compensated compass

Tags: c, arduino, accelerometer, magnetometer

I am stuck on successfully tilt compensating my 9DOF IMU using an arduino. I know this is not the usual syntax problem and rather one mathematical in nature, but can anyone help?

**The problem** is that when I move the sensor in roll and/or pitch while keeping the same yaw direction, the yaw angle does not remain constant as it should.

```
float Ax; float Ay; float Az        // these are raw accelerometer readings
float Magx; float Magy; float Magz        // these are raw magnetometer readings
float RollAngle; float PitchAngle; float YawAngle;       // these are calculated angles from raw readings

RollAngle = atan2(Ay,Az);

PitchAngle = atan2((-Ax),((Ay*sin(RollAngle)) + Az*cos(RollAngle)));

YawAngle = atan2( (Magz*sin(RollAngle)-Magy*cos(RollAngle)) , ((Magx*cos(PitchAngle))+(Magy*sin(PitchAngle)*sin(RollAngle))+Magz*sin(PitchAngle)*cos(RollAngle)) );
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You should base _all_ your calculations on only the _raw_ readings `Ax, Ay` and `aZ`. But you use calculated value Roll in Pitch and both in Yaw.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for your reply. I am not sure how you mean to accomplish that. The Roll and pitch angles have to be calculated from the raw Ax, Ay and Az and then used as phi and theta in the equations following. Or do I have it backwards/wrong? See EDIT in variable declaration and comments

Comment: This is the maths I have used as a guideline. https://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4248.pdf

Comment: If you are sure the math is OK, then my apologies. But I see a possible circularity in the calculations in which the order can influence the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have some different calculations which I recently implemented based on a ruby implementation I did sometime back.  I don't have the details at hand, I can try and find them and add them later, but I think your issue might be the use of atan2 for the pitch.
I think your calculations are based on the following equations in the data sheet you linked to.

> ```
> tan(φ) = (Gpy/Gpx)  // eq 13
> tan(θ) = (-Gpx / (Gpy sin(φ) + Gpz cos(φ))  // eq 15
> ```

where the doc says.

> Since Equations 13, 15 and 22 have an infinite number of solutions at
>   multiples of 360°, it is standard convention to restrict the solutions
>   for roll, pitch and yaw to the range -180° to 180°. A further
>   constraint is imposed on the pitch angle to limit it to the range -90°
>   to 90°. This ensures only one unique solution exists for the compass,
>   pitch and roll angles for any phone orientation. Equations **13** and 22
>   are therefore computed with a software **ATAN2** function (with output
>   angle range **-180° to 180°**) and Equation **15** is computed with a software
>   ATAN function (with output angle range **-90° to 90°**).

Here are my calculations if you are interested. (as I said I don't have the documentation handy as to how I came up with these.

```
float xM = magCurrent[0] - magOffsets[0];
float yM = magCurrent[1] - magOffsets[1];
float zM = magCurrent[2] - magOffsets[2];
float heading = (atan2(yM, xM) * 180) / Pi;
if (heading < 0) {
  heading = 360 + heading;
}
logger.infoln("Compass Heading: %f", heading);
float g = 9.8;
float xG = (accelCurrent[0] - accelOffsets[0]) / g; 
float yG = (accelCurrent[1] - accelOffsets[1]) / g; 
float zG = (accelCurrent[2] - accelOffsets[2]) / g;
float pitch = atan2(-xG, sqrt(yG * yG + zG * zG));
float roll = atan2(yG, zG);
logger.infoln("pitch: %f", pitch * 180 / Pi);
logger.infoln("roll: %f", roll * 180 / Pi);
float xM2 = xM * cos(pitch) + zM * sin(pitch);
float yM2 = xM * sin(roll) * sin(pitch) + yM * cos(roll) - zM * sin(roll) * cos(pitch);
float compHeading = (atan2(yM2, xM2) * 180 / Pi);
if (compHeading < 0) {
  compHeading = 360 + compHeading;
}
logger.infoln("tilt compensated Compass Heading: %f", compHeading);
```

Comment: Hi nPn. Thanks for your reply. I have implemented your code and I am running into the same issues. But I have not restricted the euler angles as you suggested. I simply took your code as is and inputed my variables. To get to the point, I see that you use ATAN2 for all angle calculations? And did you restrict your variables somewhere else? Does your code above give full tilt compensated headings?

Comment: I have tested your code and get equally wrong results. I have checked that the angles are all constrained. I honestly have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes to your code:

```
float pitch = atan2(-xG, zG);

float roll = atan2(yG, zG);
```

...

```
float xM2 = xM * cos(pitch) + zM * sin(pitch);

float yM2 = yM * cos(roll) - zM * sin(roll);
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes accelerometer and magnetometers are not within the same coordinate and you should first define a transformation coordinate to map the magnetometer coordinate to accelerometer coordinate. something like:
[modeling and control mark W.spong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psK53.jpg)
then you should calculate the tilt transformation considering the transformation coordinate above :
R = R1(coordinate transformation)*R2(transformation for tilt)
but usually, you can just randomly negative terms in your transformation for tilt:

```
double xhorizental = (-/+)x*cos(pitch) (-/+)y*sin(pitch)*sin(roll) 
                     (-/+)z*sin(pitch)*cos(roll);
double yhorizental = (-/+)y*cos(roll) (-/+)z*sin(roll);

heading = atan2(yhorizental,xhorizantal) (+PI)
```